# Evaluate 2 if statements and a else condition

Tags: python

I have outer and inner `if` statements and one `else` condition. Can I evaluate the two `ifs` without rewriting the exact same `else`?

```
a = 1

if a == 1:
     b = a * 5
    if b < 3:
        print(b)
else:
    print(a)
```

Basically, I'd like to evaluate the `else` if the `inner` if condition is not met.

Comment: So you have to ident it below the second `if`, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

*Updated answer after clarification of the question.*

You can just delay taking the action until after the `if/else`:

```py
a = 1

to_print = a
if a == 1:
    b = a * 5
    if b < 3:
        to_print = b

print(to_print)
```

Comment: no I can't use `and`.

Comment: Why not? Does this code give you the behaviour you want?

Comment: I updated the question. I am doing some calculation after evaluating the outer `if` / first condition.

Comment: I need a condition though - so I can use a 3rd if to check for the value of `to_print`.

Comment: I don't think you do. You should update your question with the exact outputs required given a range of inputs. Two programs with the same outputs are equivalent independent of the number of conditionals they use.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = 1
b = 2

if a == 1:
    print(a)

else if b == 1:
    print(b)

else:
    print(c)
```

Maybe you are looking for this?

Comment: Where is `c` defined?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you might try this. It should evaluate `else` for outer `if` and also evaluate inner `if`. If that what you want.

```
a = 1

if a == 1:
    b = a * 5
    print(b) if b < 3 else print(a)
else:
    print(a)
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes you have to use AND OPERATOR (&&), Because the inner condition get control only if a == 1 and inner if returns response only if b == 1
So, we have to make them one using AND Operator

```
a=1
b=2
if a==1 and b == 1 :
   print(b)
else:
   print(a)
```